# OpenMp Code stops working in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, codeblocks, reduction

I have to parallize big chunk of code in code::blocks using OpenMp. But for some reason it stops working the moment I run it. The code compiles correctly though. I ran it in Microsoft Visual Studio 12 debugger and it gives stack overflow exception. Please help. Here's the code..

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
int dxij_priv[] = {0,0,0,0};
int vt_priv[] = {0,0,0,0};
double sp_priv[Npartstot-Nboun][100][4],torquep_priv[Npartstot-Nboun][4],fmp_priv[Npartstot-Nboun][4];
for(i=Nboun+1;i<=Npartstot;++i){
    for(int n=1;n<=Nneb[i];++n){
        for(int p=1;p<=3;++p){
            sp_priv[i][n][p]=0;}}}
    for(i=Nboun+1;i<=Npartstot;++i){
        for(int p=1;p<=3;++p){
            torquep_priv[i][p]=0;
            fmp_priv[i][p]=0;
    }}
#pragma omp for nowait reduction(+:dal) reduction(+:st) reduction(+:vtang) reduction(+:sdotr)
for (i=Nboun+1;i<=Npartstot;++i){

    for (int n=1;n<=Nneb[i];++n){

        if(dxij_priv[1]>L-rng*(R[i]+R[j]))
          dxij_priv[1]=dxij_priv[1]-L;   //Same for other indices...

            else if (dxij_priv[1]<-L+rng*(R[i]+R[j])) //Same for other indices...
                  dxij_priv[1]=dxij_priv[1]+L;                

        for (int p=1;p<=3;++p){
          dal=dal+mij[p]*(vp[i][p]-vp[j][p]);
        }
        vt_priv[1]=vt_priv[1]-dxij_priv[i]; //Same for other indices
                sdotr=0;
        for (int p=1;p<=3;++p)
                    sp_priv[i][n][p] += vt_priv[p]*dt;
        for (int p=1;p<=3;++p)
                    sdotr += sp_priv[i][n][p]*dxij_priv[p];
        for (int p=1;p<=3;++p)
                    sp_priv[i][n][p] -= sdotr*dxij_priv[p]/d/d;
        for (int p=1;p<=3;++p)
                    st += sp_priv[i][n][p]*sp_priv[i][n][p];
        st=sqrt(st);
        for (int p=1;p<=3;++p)
                    vtang += vt_priv[p]*vt_priv[p];
                    vtang=sqrt(vtang);
        for (int p=1;p<3;++p) sp[i][n][p] *=st/st_prev;
        for (int p=1;p<=3;++p) tij[p]=vt_priv[p]/vtang;
        for (int p=1;p<=3;p++){
                  fmp_priv[i][p]=fmp_priv[i][p]+mij[p]*NForce+tij[p]*TForce;
                  torquep_priv[i][1]=torquep_priv[i][1]-R[i]/d*TForce*(dxij_priv[2]*tij[3]-dxij_priv[3]*tij[2]);  //Same for other indices...
                }
        } //end of n loop
        dxij[1] += dxij_priv[1];dxij[2] += dxij_priv[2];dxij[3] += dxij_priv[3];vt[1] += vt_priv[1];vt[2] += vt_priv[2];vt[3] += vt_priv[3];
    for(int z=Nboun+1;z<=Npartstot;++z)
        for(int n=1;n<=Nneb[i];++n)
            for(int p=1;p<=3;++p)
                sp[z][n][p] += sp_priv[z][n][p];
    for(int z=Nboun+1;z<=Npartstot;++z)
        for(int p=1;p<=3;++p){
            torquep[z][p] += torquep_priv[z][p];
            fmp[z][p] += fmp_priv[z][p];
    } //end of p
   }//end of i
  } //end of #pragma
```

I had to edit out some parts of the code(the actual code is much bigger than this) and I am showing only those lines that involve reductions. When I run the program on Code::Blocks I get an error prompt: Parallized.exe has stopped working.

The command for compiling is : g++ -fopenmp Parallized.cpp -lm.

I have a two core four CPU computer.

In my opinion I think I am messing up on the reduction of the array variables somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps the stack overflow is real? What is NPartsTot-Nboun? You are allocating 408*sizeof(double)*(NPartsTot-Nboun) on the stack of each thread...

Comment: Npartstot and Nboun are two constants fed to the program using another function which reads these values from a file...Their values remain same throughout the entire program...

Comment: By the way, I tried running it on linux and I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error...not sure what is going on here...

Comment: So, how big are those constants? How much space are you allocating on each stack? (Consider that if NPartsTot-Nboun == 10000, you need ~31MiB ; a thread stack is often smaller than that...). The SEGV on Linux could also be a stack overflow.

Comment: So you are telling me the space that is allocated into each stack in a single thread is smaller than that is allocated when the code runs serially? (Sorry for the late reply, I was busy with other courses).

Comment: The permissible size of the initial thread (or serial code) is controlled by the operating system and may be "unlimited". The size of thread stacks in OpenMP can be controlled by using the OMP_STACKSIZE environment variable and will not be "unlimited".